# Calling subset using column names in R

Tags: r, list, subset

I currently have created a number of subsets of data that I have named A.sub, B.sub, C.sub, etc.  I would like to use a loop to try and add a column to each of these subsets based on column name in a data.frame. For a frame with column names A, B, C, I would like to be able to call [column name].sub (e.g. A.sub, B.sub, C.sub). The name of the data.frame that I am trying to draw the column names from is called SellList. My current attempt looks like this (data simplified to show a clearer example of what I'm trying to do):

```
> SellList
                A     B     C
Sale Amount 30000 20000 10000

> A.sub
            Price   Holdings  $ Amt Owned
            101.4        400        40560

> B.sub
            Price   Holdings  $ Amt Owned
             95.5        300        28650

> C.sub
            Price   Holdings  $ Amt Owned
            154.1        100        15450

for(i in 1:width(SellList)){
  colnames(SellList[i]).sub$SaleAmount <- SellList[1,i]
}
```

With the end goal of having the subs look like:

```
> A.sub
            Price   Holdings  $AmtOwned  SaleAmount
            101.4        400      40560       30000

> B.sub
            Price   Holdings  $AmtOwned  SaleAmount
             95.5        300      28650       20000

> C.sub
            Price   Holdings  $AmtOwned  SaleAmount
            154.1        100      15450       10000
```

An alternate method that I've tried that doesn't seem to be working either is putting all of the subsets in a list and then running through the list like so:

```
for(i in length(list.level)){
  list.level[i].sub$SaleAmount <- SellList[1,i]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put the subsets into a list, this could be a job for `map2` in package *purrr*.  The `map2` function is when you have a function that involves two separate lists of the same length.  I named the list of subsets `sublist`.

```
sublist
$A.sub
  Price Holdings $ Amt Owned
1 101.4      400       40560

$B.sub
  Price Holdings $ Amt Owned
1  95.5      300       28650

$C.sub
  Price Holdings $ Amt Owned
1 154.1      100       15450
```

Now you can use `map2` to loop through `sublist` and `SellList` and combine them.  Because all of your variables are numbers, I used `cbind` but if you had mixed types you could use `data.frame` with `check.names = FALSE`.

```
library(purrr)

map2(sublist, SellList, ~cbind(.x, SaleAmount = .y))

$A.sub
  Price Holdings $ Amt Owned SaleAmount
1 101.4      400       40560      30000

$B.sub
  Price Holdings $ Amt Owned SaleAmount
1  95.5      300       28650      20000

$C.sub
  Price Holdings $ Amt Owned SaleAmount
1 154.1      100       15450      10000
```

I used the tilde coding to name the new column `SaleAmount`, where `.x.` refers to the first list and `.y` refers to the second list.

Another alternative would be to bind the subsets together into a single data.frame using `map2_df`.  Using the `.id` arguments adds a column to identify the subsets.

```
map2_df(sublist, SellList, ~cbind(.x, SaleAmount = .y), .id = "Sub")

    Sub Price Holdings $ Amt Owned SaleAmount
1 A.sub 101.4      400       40560      30000
2 B.sub  95.5      300       28650      20000
3 C.sub 154.1      100       15450      10000
```

Comment: How did you get the list of subsets? I can get a list of their names but not the data inside them.

Comment: I hard coded into them into named list while creating the objects.  See @lmo answer for an option on putting datasets in a list from your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I would solve this in base R:

```
# put .sub objects into a list
myList <- mget(ls(pattern="\\.sub$"))

# add on extra variable using lapply
myList <- lapply(seq_along(myList),
                 function(i) c(myList[[i]], "SaleAmount"=sellList[[i]][1L]))
```

This will return a nested list where the outer nest has names the A.sub, B.sub, C.sub, and the inner lists should look as in your example. Notice that this requires that the objects are named and organized as in the example.

Answer (score -2):

```
for(i in 1:length(names(SellList))){
  eval(parse(text = paste0(colnames(SellList)[i], ".sub$SaleAmount <- SellList[1,", i, "]"))
}
```

I tested only for i = 1
   A.sub
      Price Holdings AmtOwned SaleAmount
    1 101.4      400    40560      30000